# best number as a seed for random class

Tags: java, random

I want to generate random numbers between two integer numbers. In my case the numbers must meet some other conditions. I put `generator.nextInt(x)` in a loop and set seed again, if the new number doesn't meet my conditions.

The number which is generated is same in the number of loop iteration when I use `System.currentTimeMillis()` as seed.  I replace `System.currentTimeMillis()` with `System.nanoTime()`. the result much better than previous one.

I want to know is there any better way for setting the seed?

Comment: You generally don't need to seed your generator at all, unless you specifically want a repeatable sequence of outputs. Why are you seeding yours?

Comment: You should seed your random number with a random number o.0 `Mind = Blown`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the constructor for [`Random`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#Random%28%29) that doesn't take a parameter.  That constructor initializes its seed based on `System.nanoTime()` already.  Every time you invoke that constructor the seed will be different.

Generally you would only seed `Random` yourself when you want a repeatable sequence of random data (they are determinstic).

Either way, you can always keep calling `nextInt` (or any `nextXyz` method) and keep getting more random numbers without having to re-seed for every number.

Random numbers in Java are pseudo-random.  They need a seed that is used to generate the next random number.

Comment: @Mahdi the seed is to start the sequence.  For Random and some SecureRandom strategies you get the same sequence from a given seed.  It is useful if you want to reproduce the same random numbers later.

Comment: From Random's source `public Random() { this(++seedUniquifier + System.nanoTime()); }`

Comment: @Mahdi An example of this is in terrain generation with perlin noise, random numbers are taken on large, medium and small length scales and as a result the terrain looks like rolling hills but are random. The large and medium scale random numbers will be needed by many grid points, we could store them but that creates problems (in terms of creation order and storage); so being able to retrieve the sudo randoms reproducably is useful

Comment: The seeds for these random numbers are (in a round about way that im oversimplifying) based on the grid position and a master seed

Comment: @PeterLawrey Wouldn't the sequence repeat after prolonged use? Setting the seed again can prevent it if this is the case.

Comment: @wrock Random repeats after 2^48 values. If this is a worry you could reset every billion or trillion values.

Answer (score 4):

If you repeatedly use System.currentTimeMillis() it won't actually be changing that often.  i.e. once per milli-second at best.  If you use System.nanoTime() it can change every micro-second or better.

I suspect you don't need to reset the seed as the sequence is supposed to be random.  Just keep picking random numbers instead.

Comment: As wrock notes, this does repeat after 2^48 values.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to seed again. Everytime you do the `generator.nexInt(x)` you get a new random number, that is

0 <= random_number < x.