# Do I need to seed manually when using Random in java?

Tags: java, random, random-seed

In Java:

I'm aware of what `Random.setSeed(long seed);` does. I know what is a seed and how it changes with each use. Do I need to change the seed manually to ensure the sequence will not repeat after some time or it automatically manipulates the seeds using a variable (such as system clock)?

Running the same program again does not produce the same results unless I specify a seed so it must be manipulating the seed in the constructor but does it changing the seed periodically(I'm not talking about the changing of seed with each use)?

Clarification:

Seed changes with every usage but at some point the seed becomes the number it was when the Random was constructed.

Do I need to call `Random.setSeed(System.currentTimeInMillis())`; once in while to ensure the sequence will not repeat after some use?

Comment: possible duplicate of [best number as a seed for random class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17201735/best-number-as-a-seed-for-random-class)

Comment: I believe I have a problem in communication. Seed changes with every usage. After some use it becomes the number it was when the Random is constructed and starts repeating the sequence from that point. If I set the seed manually once in a while with system clock sequence, it would never repeat. But does the Random class do it itself?

The question linked does not answer my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends what you want. If I want "random" but repeatable, then I have fixed seeds. Otherwise there's little reason to fix or change the seeds.
Good reasons for seeds include:

- Testing. So the specific pattern of randoms comes up the same each time.
- Evaluation. So different test cases get the same sequence of values and so can be fairly compared.

If you really want to change the seed, or have multiple random generators with independent seeds, then create new Random objects.

Comment: Whenever a new number is produced the seed is used in some calculation and the resulting number becomes the new seed. After some use the seed becomes the same as the first time it was set. After that point the numbers produced becomes the same as the first numbers that was produced. At that point I can set the seed by hand to avoid repetition. My question is do I need to do this or the seed is altered automatically by the Random class to avoid repetition.

Comment: I think that you ought to get a *lot* of numbers before you wrap round the seeds. I've just had a quick look at the code and can't see Random making this test for you. I'd be surprised if it did. If you're calling next() that much then you're probably worried about performance as well. All those extra conditionals won't help. If you're really worried about this then write some separate code and try generating random numbers (with some seed) and seeing how long it is until the sequence repeats!

Comment: your comment is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to keep updating the seed of a `Random` object after its creation just to keep it "random".

Answer (score 0):

The parameter-less constructor already takes care of that :

```
/**
 * Creates a new random number generator. This constructor sets
 * the seed of the random number generator to a value very likely
 * to be distinct from any other invocation of this constructor.
 */
public Random();
```

Setting the seed (or supplying a seed to the constructor) is useful if you want to generate the same sequence of pseuodo-random numbers in consecutive executions of your code (which can be useful for debugging purposes).

Comment: according to what you are saying it sets the seed when constructed but it doesn't say anything about changing the seed on the fly. Not changing the seed bound to repeat the same sequence after some use.

Comment: @WVrock setting the seed for an existing Random instance has the same effect as constructing a new Random instance using the constructor that accepts a seed as an argument.